# Process returned 26866464 <0x28FE00> error

Tags: c

I'm taking a computer programming class in C and I'm trying to implement an algorithm to use for the Knight's Tour Problem. I realized that C doesn't have booleans unless you design them yourself or put '0' and '1' as true and false and be consistent with them.  I decided to use the latter, and it compiled but said "Process returned 26866464 <0x28FE00>" I wrote this program from pseudocode that was provided on the internet, I understand the idea of the Knight's Tour and this code, but I can't really point out what exactly is the mistake. I feel like it's something wrong with the way I'm printing it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define N 5

bool algorithmMove(int x, int y, int m)
{
   bool visited[N][N];
   visited[N][N] == false;

   if (x < 0 || x >= N || y < 0 || y >= N)
   {
       return false;
   }
   if (visited[x][y] == true)
   {
       return false;
   }
   if (m = (N*N) - 1)
   {
       printf("A solution has been found");
       printf("x, y");
       visited[x][y] == true;
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       bool result;
       result = false;

       result = result || algorithmMove(x+2, y+1, m+1);
       result = result || algorithmMove(x+2, y-1, m+1);
       result = result || algorithmMove(x-2, y+1, m+1);
       result = result || algorithmMove(x-2, y-1, m+1);
       result = result || algorithmMove(x+1, y+2, m+1);
       result = result || algorithmMove(x+1, y-2, m+1);
       result = result || algorithmMove(x-1, y+2, m+1);
       result = result || algorithmMove(x-1, y-2, m+1);

       if (result = true)
       {
           printf("x, y");
           return true;
       }
       else
       {
           visited[x][y] == false;
           return false;
       }
   }
}

main()
{
   algorithmMove(2, 4, 0);
}
```

Comment: No, sorry I'll make sure to edit that, I was having another problem but realized the problem and fixed it, and stackoverflow saves a draft what you write previously, my bad

Comment: You should declare your program entry point as `int main(void)` and put a `return 0;` as the last statement.  Also, in C `=` is assignment and will set the value of th variable on the left to that of the item on the right, and `==` is a test for equality.  Also arrays are indexed from 0 to N-1 (rather than 1 to N).

Comment: What happens if you remove or comment out the line (start it with `//` or put `/*` before it and `*/` after it) in the `main` function?  Does the Process still return the a non-zero value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
visited[N][N] == false;
```

This is not a assignment operator it is a comparison operator(==) and you need to fix this like

```
visited[N-1][N-1] = false; /* Array access should be within bound */
```

The same fix needs to done in multiple places.

Without initializing the array elements you use them for comparison like

```
visited[x][y] == true
```

Using uninitialized variables will cause undefined behavior